# Запятые в определении

Tags: пунктуация

Я вернулась. Кто подскажет, нужны ли здесь где-нибудь запятые?
Энергетическая безопасность Российской Федерации — это способность и готовность хозяйствующих субъектов страны своевременно обеспечивать всех потребителей в необходимом для их жизнедеятельности объеме и качестве соответствующими видами энергии по приемлемым ценам (,) с учетом существующих и прогнозируемых природных и социальных вызовов, внешних и внутренних угроз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обеспечивать КАК? ...по приемлемым ценам  и обеспечивать КАК? ...с учетом вызовов, угроз. Здесь обычные однородные обстоятельства, которые отделяются запятой.

Comment: Ответ верный, это однородные обстоятельства образа действия, семантика обстоятельств сближена в данном тексте.

Answer (score 2):

Запятую следует поставить хотя бы потому, что иначе предложение невозможно дочитать до конца и не задохнуться. )))

Обороты типа "с учетом" иногда обособляются, иногда нет. Распространенность оборота, как и предложения в целом — в пользу запятой.

Никаких однородных обстоятельств здесь нет.

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего: энергетическая безопасность - это не способность и не готовность, а состояние, которое обеспечивается (чтобы не было повтора, можно использовать слово обусловливается) способностью и готовностью субъектов...(далее по тексту). Запятую в скобках ставить не следует, иначе "с учетом ...вызовов и ...угроз" будет относиться только к "приемлемым ценам". Можно выделить запятыми оборот "в необходимом для их жизни объеме и качестве".